# python and Cocoa: about statusbar script

Tags: python, cocoa, statusbar, nsrunloop

I am creating a little script which check the number of mail in my gmail account and print them in the
status bar. The function gmail() returns the number of new emails. I have few questions, but first this is the code I wrote so far (clearly I am a novice):

```
class MyApplicationAppDelegate(NSObject):

var = 1

def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
    NSLog("Application did finish launching.")

    global ngmail

    self.statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength_(NSVariableStatusItemLength)

    while var == 1 :  
        ngmail2 = gmail();
        if  ngmail2 !=ngmail:
            self.statusItem.setTitle_("loading")
            self.statusItem.setTitle_(ngmail2)
            ngmail = ngmail2
        time.sleep(6)
```

1) Why do I need the line "self.statusItem.setTitle_("loading")" ? without that line it wouldn't update itself. I really do not know why.

2) it runs as it should, but whenever I get close to the number in the status bar, the spinning wheel appear.
I guess the reason is because I am using while, and instead I should be using something like nsrunloop or something like that. Can anyone advice on this?

3) If I put my mac to sleep and I wake it up, the script stops working. Any solution? maybe this is related to question 2) above.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your problems come from the fact that you're blocking the main thread.

In Cocoa, or almost any other GUI framework, the main thread runs a loop that waits for the next event, calls an event handler, and repeats until quit.

Your event handler, `applicationDidFinishLaunching_`, never returns. This means Cocoa can never handle the next event. Eventually, the OS will notice that you're not responding and put up the beachball.

With Cocoa, sometimes it sneaks in some other events each time you give it a chance, like on the `setTitle_` calls, and there are some things the OS can fake even if you're not responding, like keeping the window redrawing, so it isn't always obvious that your app is not responsive. But that doesn't mean you don't need to solve the problem.

There are a number ways to do this, but is the easiest is probably to use a background thread. Then, applicationDidFinishLaunching_ can kick off the background thread and then return immediately, allowing the main thread to get back to its job handling events.

The only tricky bit is that code running on background threads can't make calls to UI objects. So, what do you do about that?

That's what [`performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_waitUntilDone_`](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is for.

---

Here's an example:

```
class MyApplicationAppDelegate(NSObject):

    var = 1

    def background_work(self):
        global ngmail

        while var == 1 :  
            ngmail2 = gmail();
            if  ngmail2 !=ngmail:
                self.statusItem.setTitle_("loading")
                self.statusItem.performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_waitUntilDone_('setTitle:', ngmail2, False)
            time.sleep(6)

    def applicationDidFinishLaunching_(self, sender):
        NSLog("Application did finish launching.")
        self.statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength_(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        self.background_worker = threading.Thread(target=self.background_work)
        self.background_worker.start()
```

The only tricky bit is that you have to use the ObjC name for the selector (`setTitle:`), not the Python name (`setTitle_`).

---

However, your code has another subtle bug: `var` isn't actually synchronized, so it's possible for you to change its value in the main thread, without the background thread ever noticing.

On top of that, doing a `sleep(6)` means that it will take up to 6 seconds to quit your app, because the background thread won't get to the code that checks `var` until it finishes sleeping.

You can fix both of these by using a `Condition`.

```
class MyApplicationAppDelegate(NSObject):

    var = 1
    condition = threading.Condition()

    def background_work(self):
        global ngmail

        with condition:
            while var == 1:
                ngmail2 = gmail();
                if ngmail2 != ngmail:
                    self.statusItem.performSelectorOnMainThread_withObject_waitUntilDone_('setTitle:', ngmail2, False)
                condition.wait(6)

    @classmethod
    def shutdown_background_threads(cls):
        with condition:
            var = 0
            condition.notify_all()
```

(I assume you used a class attribute for `var` instead of an instance attribute on purpose, so I likewise made the condition a class attribute and the shutdown method a class method.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have been trying the code you wrote, but nothing happens. This is the code I am using:              `if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    delegate = MyApplicationAppDelegate.alloc().init()
    app.setDelegate_(delegate)
    AppHelper.runEventLoop()`

Comment: Please do not try to put code into comments. It's next to impossible, because SO destroys the formatting. Either edit it into your question, or put it somewhere like http://pastebin.com and post a link here. And ideally post complete code, because half the time when someone says "this answer didn't work", it turns out, after 30 minutes of back and forth, that they didn't copy it properly, or put it in the wrong place…

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. The second example just shows things that are changed from the first, the parts that are relevant to using a Condition. You still need the code from the first example. In particular, if you don't have some kind of `applicationDidFinishLaunching_` method there's nothing for Cocoa to call, and if you don't have the code that creates and starts the thread, it's never going to run. You really need to understand what code does, not just copy and paste it blindly.

Comment: Also, if you're not going to write code to call `shutdown_background_threads` at some appropriate time, it obviously isn't going to do you any good.

Comment: I tried to follow some of your code. The first example you gave me works, but with lots of errors like this one "objc[21227]: Object 0x7f930bcd6020 of class OC_PythonString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug"

Comment: the second one gave me this error: "NameError: global name 'condition' is not defined" (and it doesn't work)

Comment: @MrWoody: Yes, running any PyObjC code in a background thread without initializing a runloop for that thread will give you a lot of warnings. If you understand what's happening here, those warnings are harmless, but if you don't understand why that's true, you may be better off either using Cocoa methods for threading, starting a do-nothing runloop, etc. Meanwhile, I need to know the exact code you used for "the second one" (because, as I mentioned, that's not a complete program, just sample code) and exactly where you got the error—and that seems like a new question to open separately.

Comment: at the moment, the first code seems to be working well besides the warning which you said I can safely ignore (so far I didn't notice any memory leak). So I would first like to study the code that I have better, before I want to make any change on it. Thanks a lot for your help.